# how to deploy a process with JSF task Form in springboot application

Tags: spring-boot, camunda

according to [Camunda docs](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.15/user-guide/task-forms/jsf-task-forms/), i want to deploy a process, but i do not know how to add *.jsf as inputstream into deploymentBuilder. like this:

```
Deployment deployment = repositoryService.createDeployment()
    .name("test")
    .addString("test.bpmn20.xml", bpmn)
    .addInputStream("approveLoanRequest.jsf", new FileInputStream("src/main/webapp/approveLoanRequest.xhtml"))
    .addInputStream("submitLoanRequest.jsf", new FileInputStream("src/main/webapp/submitLoanRequest.xhtml"))
    .deploy();
```

when i want to get those renderedStartForm by `formService.getRenderedStartForm(definitionId)`,
it always is `null`

Answer (score 0):

JSF files are part of your deployment artifact (the war file). So put them into `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF`.

[Here](https://auth0.com/blog/developing-jsf-applications-with-spring-boot/) is a quite helpful tutorial.